# Verify if a system has DVD burners?

Tags: scripting, dvd, burning

Is it possible to verify if the system has a DVD burner installed? I need this for a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in a comment, there is a cleaner way of doing that: `wodim -prcap` which gives exactly what you need.

```
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
```

Also, `dmesg | grep RW`, in my case (DVD-RW/BD reader drive) it returns something like

```
[    2.399074] ata2.00: ATAPI: HL-DT-ST DVDRW/BDROM CT40N, A101, max UDMA/133
[    2.409247] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVDRWBD CT40N    A101 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
```

and `wodim dev=/dev/cdrom -scanbus`:

```
scsibus1:
        1,0,0   100) 'HL-DT-ST' 'DVDRWBD CT40N   ' 'A101' Removable CD-ROM
```

Comment: `wodim -prcap` will give you better output about the capabilities of the device.

Comment: @JodieC didn't know about this one. Added to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Simply enough: `lshal|grep dvdr`

Comment: This works if the system uses HAL, and some newer distros (e.g. Arch Linux, newer Ubuntu versions) don't.